# Permission denied when trying to run game engine on vscode on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++17, game-engine

cd "/home/gaurav/Desktop/c++ project/" && g++ olcPixelGameEngine.h -o olcPixelGameEngine && "/home/gaurav/Desktop/c++ project/"olcPixelGameEngine
bash: /home/gaurav/Desktop/c++ project/olcPixelGameEngine: Permission denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have permission to execute? Try running the shell command `chmod u+x /home/gaurav/Desktop/c++ project/olcPixelGameEngine.h`.

Comment: bash: /home/gaurav/Desktop/c++ project/olcPixelGameEngine: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error?

Comment: Now this is happening.

Comment: Are u using a virtual machine?

Comment: Ok, but are using virtual box or VMware or something like that?

Comment: Also, the file that you are compiling has a .h extension, is that a header file? If so you need to compile the `.cpp` or equivalent file(s).

Comment: How to do compile it , I was directly running the code in vccode?

Comment: If it is an executable you can just navigate to the directory, open a terminal in the context menu and run `./olcPixelGameEngine.h` in it. If it is a project I would need to see the file structure to compile it, basically you need to execute the command `g++, *.cpp` (if the extensions are .cpp) or if they are stored in different folders you would need to provide the path, like, for instance `g++ *.cpp folder1/*.cpp folder2/*.cpp` and so on, and then run `./a.out`